# slim framework sending and recieving json

Tags: php, jquery, json, slim

Im just doing a simple POST, but for some reason no matter what I do, I cant read the JSON data

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'server/account/session',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { "username": name, "password": password} ,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            sessionStorage.accessToken = data["token"];
            sessionStorage.userid = data["userid"];
            alert ( sessionStorage.accessToken );
        },


        error: function () {

        }
    });
```

`data: {"username": "chips", "password": "potato"}`

my php:

```
$result = json_decode($app->request->getBody(), true);
var_dump($result);
```

would result in NULL. I don't get why it will return NULL, I sent a json then decode it in php into a. array, isnt that what Im doing?

QUESTION TWO:
2) A related question:

if I were to send through jquery.post

```
            jQuery.post("server/account/session", { "username": name, "password": password}, function(data){
                var result = JSON.parse(data); 

                sessionStorage.accessToken = result["token"];
                sessionStorage.userid = result["userid"];

                alert ( sessionStorage.accessToken );
            });
```

and recieve it in php by
    `$userid = $app->request->params('username');`

it works perfectly, but my question is, I thought when we do POST, the data is sent through the Body instead of header. How is it that when I do jquery.post, i can recieve it by app's request->params??

EDIT:

OK I fixed the problem. Turn out even if you specify content type to be Json. It doesnt mean it will convert the data to JSON. I had to do JSON.stringify on the data.

But can anyone help me on the second question?

Comment: When you say, "I get an error" what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: 500 internal server error. I used firebug to check, and it gave me a long response, but I think the key is " Illegal string offset 'username'" Should I paste the whole thing here?

Comment: For the second question, I think that's just the way SLIM works. That's part of the ease of use, that that request object contains the POST or GET data without you having to worry so much about it. Sort of like PHP's $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage in doing so? From my understanding SSL should protect the header and body right? Thanks

Comment: None at all. You never want to pass sensitive info in the url, but as long as you are passing it through POST, you'll be safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 2; You do not have to JSON.stringify() at all, when you use the right method:

```
var data = {
    username: user,
    password: pass
};
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'server/account/session',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
})
.always(function () {
  $('body')
    .removeClass('loading');
});
```

This should generate a proper JSON-Request which would be automatically parsed into $_POST, $_REQUEST by php in general and can also be understood by Slim.